# Update table in a trigger with values from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I wanted to make a trigger which updates a table with the values of a procedure. I want the trigger to do something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER onInsertVillage AFTER INSERT ON Village
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Village V SET V.xCoordinaat = x, V.yCoordinaat = y FROM getVrijePlaatsInMap();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But this doesn't work.. The procedure returns an x and y value by the way. Is there a possible way to make the trigger do it's job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the trigger shall adapt `xCoordinaat` and `yCoordinat` for every new village inserted into table `Village`. If this is the case, I would use an `BEFORE INSERT`-trigger, which has access to the values of the respective village record to be inserted (before it is inserted). In absence of schema and stored procedure code of your example, I wrote a simplified program demonstrating this approach:

```sql
create table test (
    a int,
    b int,
    c int
);


CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN a int, OUT b INT, OUT c int)
BEGIN
  set b = a div 100;
  set c = a % 100;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER test_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   call simpleproc (new.a,new.b,new.c);
END;

insert into test (a,b,c) values (120,0,0), (210,0,0), (303,0,0);
```

this yields:

```
  a | b | c
----|---|---
120 | 1 | 20
210 | 2 | 10
303 | 3 | 3
```

Getting your approach working might be a little bit more tricky; In an `AFTER INSERT`-trigger, you have access to the `.NEW`-values, but you cannot modify them; Hence, you have to do an update on the table, but you somehow have to identify the village that has just been inserted.