# Insert values into a table using a trigger with values from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm a newbie here. So, please feel free to correct me if my code or  thinking approach can be worked upon.

I am working in MySQL Workbench and MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client. I have a database called *ds_testdb2* with its tables
structured as follows:

*ds_testdb2*

-Tables:

1. asset_sensor_table
2. device_table
3. mapped_readings_table
4. readings_table
5. sensor_table

I need to execute the following SELECT statement every time a record is inserted in my *readings_table* (insertion into the readings_table happens approx. every 1 minute). This SELECT statement joins 4 tables and produces a mapping of the device's imei with other device attributes such as device_id, subscription_id,etc from another database named *agiletest*. This SELECT statement works correctly.

```
SELECT r.imei, r.send_time, r.latitude, r.longitude, r.temperature, r.ground_velocity,
        d.sys_id  AS device_id, d.model_id, d.Subscription_ID,
        s.id AS sensor_id, s.type_id AS sensor_type,
        a_s.asset_id, a_s.start_time, a_s.end_time
        FROM 
        ds_testdb2.readings_table r JOIN agiletest.device d ON  r.imei= d.imei
        JOIN agiletest.sensor s ON d.sys_id= s.device_id 
        JOIN agiletest.asset_sensor a_s ON s.id= a_s.sensor_id;
```

So, I put this SELECT statement in a Stored Procedure. This SP works correctly as well.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `ds_testdb2`.`mapping_2`()
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `ds_testdb2`.`mapped_readings_table`  -- mapped_readings-table already existed, but was empty.
        (`imei`, `send_time`, `latitude`, `longitude`,`temperature`,`ground_velocity`,
        `device_id`,`model_id`,`subscription_id`,
        `sensor_id`,`sensor_type`,
        `asset_id`,`start_time`,`end_time`) -- no 'VALUES' keyword      
        SELECT r.imei, r.send_time, r.latitude, r.longitude, r.temperature, r.ground_velocity,
        d.sys_id  AS device_id, d.model_id, d.Subscription_ID,
        s.id AS sensor_id, s.type_id AS sensor_type,
        a_s.asset_id, a_s.start_time, a_s.end_time
        FROM 
        ds_testdb2.readings_table r JOIN agiletest.device d ON  r.imei= d.imei
        JOIN agiletest.sensor s ON d.sys_id= s.device_id 
        JOIN agiletest.asset_sensor a_s ON s.id= a_s.sensor_id;    
    END  $$
```

I then run the Stored Procedure:

```
mysql> call mapping_2;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Now, this SP needs to be executed every time a record is inserted in my readings_table. So, I created a trigger that says:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER initial_table_mapping_1 AFTER INSERT ON readings_table
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> call mapping_2();
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

Now, To check the execution of the trigger, I am doing the following steps in MySQLWorkbench:

--Step 1. Insert 1 record into the readings_table

```
INSERT INTO readings_table -- (imei,send_time, latitude, longitude, temperature, ground_velocity)
VALUES
(354721090118251, '2019-04-07 21:26:48',43.63218, -79.51890, 108, 50);
```

> > Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

--Step 2. execute the trigger
-already ran it in the MySQL Command Prompt
-Response was:  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

Step 3. check if the mapped_readings_table was updated(current #rows= 16)

```
select * from mapped_readings_table;
```

-still stuck with the Error from Step1.

My Question is: In Step1, how can I rewrite my trigger such that-  the result  set from my Stored Procedure gets stored in my *mapped_readings_table*, everytime  a record is inserted in my *readings_table*? And, are my steps (Step 1,2,3) to verify the execution of my trigger, correct?

A similar question is here: [Update table in a trigger with values from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624559/update-table-in-a-trigger-with-values-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: Have you tried using a stored function instead?

Comment: @Uueerdo: not yet. I'm not familiar with them. Would you suggest writing a stored_function in place of a stored_procedure, and then call that stored_function using a Trigger?

Comment: Stored functions cannot return result sets; MySQL may disallow proc calls in triggers since procs _can_ return results.

Comment: @Uueerdo: umm..I'm still not sure how to solve this query. How do you suggest I approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
My trigger above worked perfectly, and is the right trigger to do the job I had in mind. The problem was that I had created many dummy-triggers to see if my trigger was working.

So, AFTER INSERT ON readings_table, it was these old, dummy triggers that were getting executed, not the final one. The problem was solved once I deleted the old triggers and only had the right trigger in my system.